# How to disable selection of list markers in NSTextView (like Notes)

Tags: cocoa, nstextview, richtext

I'm working on a Mac app that allows rich-text editing in the description of an item, including list items.

All of that is working fine, but by default NSTextView allows the user to select and edit the list markers just like normal text. I want the text view to behave like notes, where list markers are not selectable.

Here's an NSTextView (from TextEdit):

[image: TextEdit Lists]

and here's the same in Notes:

[image: Notes lists]

I'm able to get close by overriding `-[NSTextView setSelectedRanges:affinity:stillSelecting:]`, and removing the marker ranges. Unfortunately that interferes with many standard editing actions, including the arrow keys.

I could certainly override those actions (defined in NSResponder), but that's starting to seem like a lot of work. Is there a simpler way?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I ran into the same issue today.